# Merits of defining constants in header or implementation files

Tags: c++

Throughout a C++ codebase I'm working in, the pattern for declaring constants looks something like this.

```
// module_constants.h
#ifndef MODULE_CONSTANTS
#define MODULE_CONSTANTS

namespace module {

extern const int SOME_CONST;

}

#endif
```

```
// module_constants.cpp
#include "module_constants.h"

namespace module {

const int SOME_CONST = 1;

}
```

What are the merits of this approach rather than defining all of the constant values in the header?

Answer (score 5):

The single advantage I know of is that you only have to recompile a single cpp-file when you change the constant’s value and not every file that directly or indirectly includes the header file.

That can be particularly useful when you provide a dynamically linked library and want to patch it without recompiling the actual application.

Some drawbacks are that

- (as latedeveloper wrote) you can't use them at places where a constant expression is required (e.g. array bounds or template parameters) outside of the cppfile, in which you defined it.
- you make the optimizer's life harder.
- from a tooling perspective e.g. intellisense won't show you it's value.

Comment: Anything wrong with my answer or why the downvote? I'm always happy to learn new things.

Answer (score -2):

Well, by putting it in the header you'd run into the one-definition rule if you include it in more than one cpp file.

But, on the other hand, you can create it as a constexpr in the header I believe.

Comment: `const int SOME_CONST = 1;` is just fine in a header. There's no ODR problem, because `SOME_CONST` has internal linkage.

Comment: Doesn't this affect linking, too? I.e. what happens if you change the value of the const if it's in the `.cpp` vs the `.h`?